# How to get value of a variable starting with - hyphen from values.yaml file for helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

My values file looks like below :

```
hosts:
  - host: abc.defg.hij.io
```

I need to get the host value "abc.defg.hij.io" to ingress file

tried with tpl function which was not helpful

Comment: Could you share more details? Like what helm chart do you use (or what does your Ingress template file look like)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is intended to be used within a `{{ range }}` ... `{{ end }}` block (see https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

For example, I have this in my `values.yaml`

```
ingress:
  ...

  # Hosts to recognise on the ingress
  # External DNS will create DNS entries for these
  hosts:
    - host: host1.domain.com
    - host: host2.domain.com
    - host: host3.domain.com
```

Then in my `ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
                port: 
                  number: {{ $svcPort }}
    {{- end }}
```

Notice how the "current" value being selected in the range is referenced as "`{{ . }}`" and therefore "{{ .host }}" means "the host value of the currently selected element of the range"

The `range` block will duplicate that block as many times as there are items in the range, so in my example, there's going to be block for host1, host2 and host3